# NodeJS - npm package - html-pdf alternate

Tags: node.js, npm, pdf-generation, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I am creating a pdf from a static HTML code in nodejs using **html-pdf** npm package. But it is critical severity vulnerability. I want to change this package. Is there any package available to convert an HTML code to PDF on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

yes, sir... u can use Puppeteer.
Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. Puppeteer runs headless by default but can be configured to run full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium.